# Is there a stand-alone chat client for Battle.net?

Tags: battle.net

I enjoy Steam; even when not playing a game through steam, I like the ability to chat with those on my friends list.

Blizzard's Battle.net service is aspiring to do something similar, and with its new Real ID system, I don't need to own (or subscribe to) World of Warcraft to interact with those who do.

However, at the moment, the only other Battle.net game is Starcraft 2, which is fine and dandy when I'm actually playing it, but if I just want to talk to my friends, it's more of a hassle, as running Starcraft 2 and alt-tabbing back and forth between whatever it is I'm doing is tedious at best.

Is there a stand alone chat client I can use over Battle.net such that I can chat with my Battle.net friends when not in a battle.net enabled game?

Comment: I've been meaning to ask this question for a while... I've been spoiled by Steam, where the chat client IS standalone.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The recently released [Battle.net Desktop App](http://us.battle.net/en/app/) now includes the ability to chat with your friends if they are logged on to that same app, or any of WoW, SCII, D3, Hearthstone, Heroes of the Storm or Overwatch.

[image: Battle.net Desktop App]

Answer (score 7):

I shortcut all Games in Steam, even WoW and Starcraft 2. Starting the Games from the Steam lib works without probs. That way they benefit from the steam chat function. As long as your pals do the same you have no problem chatting across games. Tell your pals, tell everyone. Make it the popular thing ;)

Comment: I do this too.  It's the best of both worlds.

Comment: "As long as your pals do the same thing" is exactly the problem, unfortunately. I do this for things like League of Legends, though.

Comment: Almost everybody I know has Steam nowadays. There is no way around it with more and more games requiring online activation through steam.

Answer (score 4):

No. Blizzard is *slowly* moving in this direction, with the [recent announcement](http://forums.worldofwarcraft.com/thread.html?sid=1&topicId=26850248319) that players will be able to access their World of Warcraft guilds chat, as well as direct messaging with guild members via the [Armory](http://www.wowarmory.com/) and it's Mobile apps for iPhone and Android.

As to when this feature is expanded to Battle.net as a whole? Nothings been announced, but I doubt you could go wrong with Blizzards characteristic 'Soon™'.

Comment: I'll keep an eye out for this and try to make sure I update this question if the answer ever changes.

Comment: Psssst! *Wink*. *Wink*. It only took them 3.5 years!