# Can I talk to friend logged in WoW without being logged in?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a stand-alone chat client for Battle.net](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10890/is-there-a-stand-alone-chat-client-for-battle-net)

Is there any software that allows me to use the WoW chat without being logged in ? Can I talk a friend that is playing WoW, without playing myself (suppose I do have an account but I just don't want to log in) ?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing official, and Blizzard is notorious about not allowing third party software to use their systems.

One way you could use the battle.net chat system without being logged into WoW, would be to play on another Blizzard game such as Starcraft 2 (which uses the same battle.net ID & chat system, but does not require any kind of subscription). But you will need to log into your battle.net account on a Blizzard game. Just not necessarily WoW.

Comment: ya, knew about sc2 to wow. that's were the idea came from (to look for external chat). thx anyways